# Get DB owner's name in PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql

I have DB "test" in PostgreSql. I want to write sql to get owner my database.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

You can find such things in the system catalog

```
SELECT d.datname as "Name",
pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(d.datdba) as "Owner"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_database d
WHERE d.datname = 'database_name'
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: 'your_name'?? What is this? I need to pass something that I don't know in order to know something?

Comment: @DanielMöller You would know the DB name. It's just the owner of the given DB that you're trying to ascertain. If you don't know the DB name, then just omit that WHERE clause.

Comment: I meant to say "name" of the given DB above.

Comment: You can use `current_database()` if you need to dynamically find out which database you are connected to and which owner you are interested in.

Comment: You can remove the `where` clause to get owners of all databases in the current cluster.

Answer (score 98):

If you use the [psql](http://postgresguide.com/utilities/psql.html) command-line tool, you can simply use `\l`

Comment: This returns a list of databases, but the owners of the databases.

Comment: @Flimm I didn't understand your comment - this returns a list of all existing DBs on the server (that current user has permission to view) with the owner of each DB.

Comment: You're right. I was using `pgcli` which for some reason gives a different result.

Comment: This works beautifully and simply. 2 characters is the way to do it. lol

Answer (score 45):

You can use the combination of `pg_database`, `pg_users` system tables  and `current_database()` function in this way:

```
 SELECT u.usename 
 FROM pg_database d
  JOIN pg_user u ON (d.datdba = u.usesysid)
 WHERE d.datname = (SELECT current_database());
```

Comment: This won't work if database is owned by a role (a group of users) and not a user.

Comment: current_catalog is a synonym for current_database() 

```SELECT u.usename 
 FROM pg_database d
  JOIN pg_user u ON (d.datdba = u.usesysid)
 WHERE d.datname = current_catalog;```

Answer (score 15):

can just cast the role OID with magic ::regrole to give the role name of owner:

```
SELECT datdba::regrole FROM pg_database WHERE datname = 'test' ;
```

Answer (score 4):

This work with database owned by group role:

```
SELECT
    U.rolname
   ,D.datname
FROM
    pg_roles AS U JOIN pg_database AS D ON (D.datdba = U.oid)
WHERE
    D.datname = current_database();
```

Using `pg_authid` (as I did in my previous version) instead of `pg_roles` is limited to SuperUser because it holds password (see [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-authid.html)):

> Since this catalog contains passwords, it must not be publicly
>   readable. `pg_roles` is a publicly readable view on `pg_authid` that
>   blanks out the password field.

Comment: When running this, it gave permission denied for relation pg_authid. What's required?

Comment: @StevenYong, Thank you for pointing this out, I have updated my answer. Reading the doc, it is sufficient to replace `pg_authid` by `pg_roles`. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

The follwing query displays info for all tables in the public schema:

```
 select t.table_name, t.table_type, c.relname, c.relowner, u.usename
 from information_schema.tables t
 join pg_catalog.pg_class c on (t.table_name = c.relname)
 join pg_catalog.pg_user u on (c.relowner = u.usesysid)
 where t.table_schema='public';
```

source :http://cully.biz/2013/12/11/postgresql-getting-the-owner-of-tables/

Answer (score 0):

Remember in SQL including postgres that you have a heirarchy within a given sql server instance: `catalog/db > schema > tables`

When looking for perms/metadata for **within** a catalog you want to look at `information_schema`

**Example:** `information_schema.role_table_grants` for table perms

**Example:** `information_schema.role_usage_grants` for SEQUENCE/schema perms

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/information-schema.html

For catalog/db-level config/meta, you need to look another level up in `pg_catalog`.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalogs.html

**Example:**

```sql
SELECT dbs.datname, roles.rolname
  FROM pg_catalog.pg_database dbs, pg_catalog.pg_roles roles
 WHERE dbs.datdba = roles.oid;
```

`pg_catalog.pg_database.datdba` has ID of owner role.

`pg_catalog.pg_roles.oid` has ID of owner role (join)

`pg_catalog.pg_roles.rolname` has name/string of owner role