# Error:must be owner of database

Tags: database, postgresql, psql

I want to delete a particular database which I have named 'mysitedb' so what I did is I opened the terminal and entered the command 'dropdb mysitedb' then the error 'ERROR:  must be owner of database mysitedb' pops up. I know the username and pass for the particular database but don't have a clue on deleting it. I am new to postgresql. be gentle :P

Comment: Apparently you *don't* know the username/password for a Postgresql user with *permission* to delete the database.  That's what you need to get.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165254/get-db-owners-name-in-postgresql This will show you how to find the user who owns the database.

Comment: NOTE: I know the user who owns it

Comment: also I know the password.but I dont know how to login

Comment: `dropdb <database_name> -U <owner_username> -W` It will ask you for the password

Comment: Thanks @PhilipCouling that was the solution. I thought I knew who owned the table, but after doing that query I figured out how really did.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to delete a particular database which I have named
> 'mysitedb' so what I did is I opened the terminal and entered the
> command 'dropdb mysitedb' then the error 'ERROR: must be owner of
> database mysitedb' pops up...

OK - this means you probably don't have the right credentials.  You need the username/password of a PostgreSQL user with permissions to delete that database.

> NOTE: I know the user who owns it.  Also I know the password.

Then who were you logged in as when you got the permissions error?

Anyway, you want the [dropdb](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-dropdb.html) command:

`dropdb -U db_owner_username -i [-h host] mysitedb`

Here is the [PostgreSQL documentation page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/manuals/).

Here is how to confirm ownership:

```
SELECT d.datname as "Name",
pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(d.datdba) as "Owner"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_database d
WHERE d.datname = 'database_name'
ORDER BY 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

First switch the cli user:

```
sudo su postgres
```

Then connect to your database normally.